# Spring kerberos Authentication Times Out

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kerberos, spring-ldap

I have a spring boot application that authenticates via Kerberos. The `KerberosLdapContextSource` accepts a list of LDAP URLs as one of it's constructor parameters. I use this parameter to pass the LDAP URL of each of our ActiveDirectory nodes (they're behind an SLB but Kerberos doesn't accept that). I was under the impression that if one of the nodes is not available the Kerberos library will automatically switch to another node. However, this is not the case. What in fact happens is that the authentication times out.

Do I have the wrong impression of the library? 
Can this automatic switching of nodes depending on availability be achieved?

Comment: AFAIK the Java implementation of Kerberos uses a custom param in `krb5.conf` to override the default timeout -- before Java 9 the param was undocumented (!!) and the default was 30s (!!!) ; nowadays there is some doc in the Java technical papers but well hidden _(and still nothing in MIT Kerberos docs since they don't use that Java extension)_ and I'm not sure about the new default...

Comment: Also, make sure `krb5.conf` disables UDP -- which is historically the default, but is a big source of cryptic issues...